# How can i implement a for loop to animate using anime.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, anime.js

I am trying to implement a for loop for my page loader using JQuery and the framework [anime.js](http://animejs.com/)

```js
    var testimonialElements = $(".loader-animation");
    for(var i=0; i< Elements.length; i++){
        var element = Elements.eq(i);
        //do something with element
    
         var basicTimeline = anime.timeline();
           basicTimeline
      .add({
        targets: element,
        opacity: {
        value: ['1','0'],
        duration: 2000,
        delay: 4000
      },
      letterSpacing: {
        value: ['30px','10px'],
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'easeInOutSine'
      }
    });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container on-loader"> 
     <h2 class="loader-animation">Case1</h2>
    <h2 class="loader-animation">Case2</h2>
    <h2 class="loader-animation">Case3</h2>
    <h2 class="loader-animation">Case4</h2>
    </div>
```

The issue is , the script is not looping through and initiating the animation for each loop .

Extremely sorry if the question is simple , I am new to javascript & anime.js framework.

Comment: You want to annimate every text after each other ?

Comment: yes exactly , one after the other

Comment: the problem that i face is in initializing the animation for every loop

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use loop , first you passe the `.loader-animation` selector to your anime and you have just to use a [callback](http://animejs.com/documentation/#allCallbacks) function , in which it return the current element and it's order between all the elements (1,2,3. ...) and multiply the delay by the order of this last :
(after you can play on the delay second to sweet your intention )

See below working Snippet

```js
var basicTimeline = anime.timeline();
basicTimeline.add({
  targets: ".loader-animation",
  opacity: {
    value: ['1', '0'],
    duration: 2000,
    delay: function(el, i) {
      $(el).removeClass("otherclass");
      return 2000 * (i + 1);
    },
  },
  letterSpacing: {
    value: ['30px', '10px'],
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    delay: function(el, i) {
      return 2000 * (i);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<div class="container on-loader">
  <h2 class="loader-animation otherclass">Case1</h2>
  <h2 class="loader-animation otherclass">Case2</h2>
  <h2 class="loader-animation otherclass">Case3</h2>
  <h2 class="loader-animation otherclass">Case4</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , Works like a charm . Just one question .

Comment: Lets take the case that for each [i] in .loader-animation i need to toggle a class which is present alogn with .loader-animation . This wont work well then if im not wrong .

Comment: Plus , if you could explain why the above for loop went wrong , would be the best .

Comment: Well , for you can remove the class , in the callback function , see my updated answer , You have just to wrap the return element (el) and remove the desired class .

Comment: and for your example , first thing is in anime js targets must be a selector not a node , so if try by example to access by for loop you have to just set every loop the targets  to `targets:"loader-animation:nth-child("+(i+1+)")` , and in this case all the annimation will trigger at the same time .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166203/discussion-between-boo-berrita-and-titus-saju).